# Negative lookbehind in RegEx: Matching multiple POS-tags at once

Tags: regex, tags, linguistics, negative-lookbehind

I am still fairly new to regex, so I would appreciate any help.
I am trying to use regular expressions to find specific grammatical patterns in a text corpus that was part-of-speech-tagged using the CLAWS7 tagset.
Here is a sample:

> Ya_UH and_CC then_RT uhm_NN1 we_PPIS2 wrote_VVD in_RP but_CCB already_RR taken_VVN up_RP that_DD1 day_NNT1 that_CST we_PPIS2 wanted_VVD actually_RR they_PPHS2 said_VVD still_RR available_JJ you_PPY know_VV0 so_RR by_II that_DD1 time_NNT1 we_PPIS2 we_PPIS2 write_VV0 in_II our_APPGE letter_NN1 two_MC weeks_NNT2 later_RRR already_RR taken_VVN up_RP Quite_RG good_RR uh_UH P ICE-SIN:S1A-001#74:1:B Ask_VV0 her_PPHO1 I_PPIS1 left_VVD my_APPGE house_NN1 at_II one_MC1 met_VVD
> PRO_NN1 in_II school_NN1 at_II two_MC Ya_PPY so_RR waited_VVD you_PPY know_VV0 they_PPHS2 say_VV0 half_DB hour_NNT1 later_RRR And_CC and_CC it_PPH1 was_VBDZ
> still_RR drizzling_JJ and_CC raining_VVG

The pattern I am looking for is every instance of `\w*\_V.*?` (= every verb) that is **not** preceded by a pronoun. Pronouns can have these tags:

> _PN _PN1 _PNQO _PNQS _PNQV _PNX1 _PPGE _PPH1  _PPHO1  _PPHO2  _PPHS2  _PPIO1  _PPIO2  _PPIS1  _PPIS2 _PPX1    _PPX2 _PPY

In the sample, the desired regex should ideally match:

```
taken_VVN
met_VVD 
Ask_VV0
waited_VVD
raining_VVG
```

Using the negative lookbehind, I managed to create the following expression, which only matches verbs that are not preceded by a _PPIS2 tag:

```
(?<!\_PPIS2)\s\w*\_V.*?
```

What could I do to extend it to all the other pronoun tags? I've tried the expressions below, but they either do not match anything at all or match the wrong instances.

```
(?<!\_P.*)\s\w*\_V.*? (no match)
(?<![\_P.*])\s\w*\_V.*? (wrong results)
```

Any ideas or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Try `\b(?:[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+ )?(?<!_PN |_PN1 |_PNQ[OVS] |_PNX1 |_PPGE |_PPH1 |_PPHO[12] |_PPHS2 |_PPIO[12] |_PPIS[12] |_PPX[12] |_PPY )[^\W_]*_V\w*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LsoPSm/1).

Comment: I‘ve edited the post; I’m sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this PCRE regex in sublime:

```sh
\b\w*_P\w*\h+\w*_V\w*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\w*_V\w*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hsSiQr/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b\w*_P\w*`: Match a word with `_P` in it
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `\w*_V\w*`: Match a word with `_V` anywhere
- `(*SKIP)(*F)`: skip and fail the matched substrings
- `|`: OR
- `\b\w*_V\w*`: Match a word with `_V` anywhere (these are our matches)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there would be a smarter pattern but with Sublime Text 3 you could use a combination of `(*SKIP)(*F)` to first match what you don't want, discard those matched, then match what you do want:

```
_P(?:N(?:X?1|Q[OSV]|)|P(?:GE|H1|(?:[HI]O|IS|X)[12]|HS2|Y))\s\w+_V[A-Z0-9]*\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+_V[A-Z0-9]*\b
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/if4L4N/1). Since all your words end on an underscore followed by the appropriate grammatical pattern I think it should fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
\b(?:[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+ )?(?<!_PN |_PN1 |_PNQ[OVS] |_PNX1 |_PPGE |_PPH1 |_PPHO[12] |_PPHS2 |_PPIO[12] |_PPIS[12] |_PPX[12] |_PPY )[^\W_]*_V\w*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LsoPSm/1).

*Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+ )?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[^\W_]+` - one or more letters/digits
  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[^\W_]+`  - one or more letters/digits and a space
- `(?<!_PN |_PN1 |_PNQ[OVS] |_PNX1 |_PPGE |_PPH1 |_PPHO[12] |_PPHS2 |_PPIO[12] |_PPIS[12] |_PPX[12] |_PPY )` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if any of the patterns above appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^\W_]*` - zero or more digits/letters
- `_V`  - a `_V` string
- `\w*` - any zero or more word chars.